# MySQLdb module works when running Python script from the command line, but not as a cron job

Tags: python, cron, mysql-python

I am trying to create a cron job to run a python script I wrote, but for some reason the script only runs when I'm running it from the command line.  It worked before, but I accidentally deleted my crontab.  When the crontab I just wrote tries to run it, I get an error about the MySQLdb module being the wrong architecture:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myuser/Documents/EE_SFDC Integration/csv_reader/Weekly_Updates/Weekly_Confirmation/weekly_confirm.py", line 7, in <module>
    import MySQLdb
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture
```

In my crontab, I've tried using the full path to several python versions (2.7 and 3.4), but I still get the issue.  When I use 3.4, I don't get an error about MySQLdb, but I *do* get an error on a print .forma() statement being the wrong syntax.

But again, that doesn't happen when I run the script from the command line, so I expect this is not the correct version either.

The cron job looks like this:

```
14 12 * * * today=`date +"\%Y-\%m-\%d"` && /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2 /Users/myuser/Documents/EE_SFDC\ Integration/csv_reader/Weekly_Updates/Weekly_Confirmation/weekly_confirm.py > /Users/myuser/Documents/EE/run_logs/weekly_sync_runlog_$today.txt 2>&1
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message typically means that you have a mismatch between the MySQLdb (or a dependency) and Python architecture.

That is, one of them are most likely 64-bit, while the other is 32-bit.

What happens if you try the following in a terminal?

```
$ /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2
(Take note of the exact version)
>>> import platform
>>> print platform.architecture()
>>> import MySQLdb
```

Do it again, but this time with python from your path and see if they differ

```
$ python
>>> import platform
>>> print platform.architecture()
>>> import MySQLdb
```

Edit:

You might also check with file, what architecture the module is built for.

```
$ file /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so (for architecture x86_64):  Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so (for architecture i386):    Mach-O bundle i386
```

Comment: Thank you!  I see an error when I attempt to import MySQLdb the first way you suggested `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2`  and not when I simply run Python from my path.  With that in mind, how can I figure out what version of Python (and what filepath to use) in my cronjob?

Comment: Also, running Python via `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2` and then running `print platform.architecture()` returns `('64bit', '')` , which threw an error when I attempted to import MySQLdb vs when I run from PATH, which returns `('32bit', '')` which didn't throw an error on import so clearly I need to run the 32bit version of Python.

Comment: I think I found the answer... Does `arch -i386 /usr/bin/python` sound right?